# How to enlarge and change page header smoothly with ScrollMagic when user is scrolled all the way up?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scrollmagic

I would like the height of the header to be increased along with the logo, plus some extra titles for icons appear once there's space for those. The features should happen only when user scrolled up, but I'd like the transition to happen smoothly.

I experimented with Tweens with scale transformation, but when the logo is enlarged, I don't only want a visual magnification (which I assume happens), but the image dimension to be increased properly and the logo to reveal in that scale.

```
let controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
new ScrollMagic.Scene({offset: "1"})
  .setClassToggle("#header-row", "compact-header")
  .addTo(controller);
new ScrollMagic.Scene({offset: "1"})
  .setClassToggle(".header-button-title", "hidden")
  .addTo(controller);
if ($('#powered_by').length > 0)
  new ScrollMagic.Scene({offset: "1"})
    .setClassToggle("#powered_by", "hidden")
    .addTo(controller);
if ($('.vcfix').length > 0)
  new ScrollMagic.Scene({offset: "1"})
    .setClassToggle(".vcfix", "hidden")
    .addTo(controller);
```

So I went for setClassToggle to add/remove classes from the needed elements. My problem is that there's no transition and the change happens abruptly. Is there a way to have the change happen smoothly? I know that the effect of class addition / removals are indirect, so for a smooth transition the framework would have to take the end point and the start point. I'm not even sure it's possible.

Comment: Is there a way to control the timeline of the class addition result with a Tween + GSAP?

Comment: Or using Animate.css to add animation classes, but then somehow it'd be good to have animation for both fade in and fade out...